# Value of a+b and char type

Tags: c++, return-value, unsigned-char

I am working in C++ and I had (as an exercise) to write on paper 2 answers.
The first question: if we have the following declarations and initialisations of variables:

```
unsigned char x=250, z=x+7, a='8';
```

What is the value of the expression?

```
z|(a-'0') // (here | is bitwise disjunction)
```

We have unsigned char, so the number `z=x+7` is reduced mod 256, thus, after writing the numbers in binary, the answer is 9.

---

The next question: a and b are int variables, `a=1` and `b=32767`.

The range of int is `[-32768, 32767]`. We don't have an unsigned type here. My question is: what is the value of `a+b`? How does this work with signed data types if the value of a certain variable is greater than the range of that data type?

Comment: What do _you_ think the value of a+b is?

Comment: -32768 but I want to see how this actually works.

Comment: "here | is bitwise disjunction" - yes, we know that

Comment: One question at a time, please.

Comment: Actually, there is only one question. I solved the first and explained the way I solved it. The first question is only to explain my struggle.

Comment: What does the first question have to do with the second question? I'm really confused.

Comment: Because unsigned types allow mod 2^n arithmetic and I was wondering if this also works for signed data types without to be considered undefined behavior.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> The next question: a and b are int variables, `a=1` and `b=32767`.
>
> [...]My question is: what is the value of `a+b`?

Its [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).  We cant tell you what it will be.  We could make a reasonable guess but as far as C++ is concerned signed integer overflow is undefined behavior.

Comment: undefined behavior or implementation defined? I mean the difference described here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2397984/undefined-unspecified-and-implementation-defined-behavior

Comment: @user6261180 No problem.  It is a little short but I wanted didn't want to explain what is happening for you since it may not happen to everyone.

Answer (score 1):

There is no `operator+(unsigned char, unsigned char)` in C++, it first promotes these `unsigned char` arguments to `int` and only then does the addition, so that the type of the expression is `int`.

And then that `int` whose value is too big to fit in `unsigned char` gets converted to `unsigned char`.

The standard says:

> A prvalue of an integer type can be converted to a prvalue of another integer type. A prvalue of an unscoped enumeration type can be converted to a prvalue of an integer type. If the destination type is unsigned, the resulting value is the least unsigned integer congruent to the source
>   integer (modulo 2**n where n is the number of bits used to represent the unsigned type). [ Note: In a two’s complement representation, this conversion is conceptual and there is no change in the bit pattern (if there is no truncation). — end note ]

Answer (score 0):

For the second question, the answer is undetermined.

You can verify it yourself like this :

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int a = 1;
    int b = 32767;
    int c = a+b;
    cout << c << endl;
}
```

The result will depend on your machine.

Comment: An `int` can have the range [-32768, 32767].

Comment: *For the second question, the answer is indeed -32768* it may be on your machine and the OP's machine but in C++ it is UB.  You cannot say it will always be -32768